# getStringExtra() not working in Adapter Class

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get the pass the current user data into the this adapter class. However, I failed to use the `getStringExtra()` where it keep mentions that the `getStringExtra()` is an resolved reference. why?

```
 class ItemAdapter(
    //private var gList:List<GoalList> = ArrayList(),
    private var iList: ArrayList<ItemList> = ArrayList(),
    private val context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

    private var connection : Connection? = null
    private var statement : Statement? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val v: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.activity_item_list, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return iList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val list = iList[position]
        holder.category.text = list.iCategory
        holder.exAmount.text = list.iAmount.toString()
        holder.eDate.text = list.iDate
        holder.eNote.text = list.iNote

        val sqlCon = SQLCon()
        connection = sqlCon.connectionClass()!!

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener {
            try
            {
                val sql : String= "DELETE FROM Expenses where Category = '${list.iCategory}' "
                statement = connection!!.createStatement()
                statement!!.executeUpdate(sql)
            }
            catch (e : Exception)
            { }
        }
        holder.update.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener
        {
            override fun onClick(view: View?) {

                val intent = Intent(view!!.context, EditExpensesActivity::class.java)
                //var currentUser = view!!.context.getIntent().getStringExtra("Logged In User")
         
                intent.putExtra("CurrentUser", currentUser)
                intent.putExtra("eCategory", holder.category.text)
                intent.putExtra("eAmount", holder.exAmount.text)
                intent.putExtra("eNote", holder.eNote.text)
                view.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Place code in `code` blocks properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int,intent:Intent) {
        val list = iList[position]
        holder.category.text = list.iCategory
        holder.exAmount.text = list.iAmount.toString()
        holder.eDate.text = list.iDate
        holder.eNote.text = list.iNote

        val sqlCon = SQLCon()
        connection = sqlCon.connectionClass()!!

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener {
            try
            {
                val sql : String= "DELETE FROM Expenses where Category = '${list.iCategory}' "
                statement = connection!!.createStatement()
                statement!!.executeUpdate(sql)
            }
            catch (e : Exception)
            { }
        }
        holder.update.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener
        {
            override fun onClick(view: View?) {

                val intent = Intent(view!!.context, EditExpensesActivity::class.java)
                var currentUser = intent.getStrinExtra("Logged In User")
         
                intent.putExtra("CurrentUser", currentUser)
                intent.putExtra("eCategory", holder.category.text)
                intent.putExtra("eAmount", holder.exAmount.text)
                intent.putExtra("eNote", holder.eNote.text)
                view.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        })
    }
```